# Did the wealth gap shrink under Trump (pre-pandemic)?

Tags: united-states, economics

https://www.wsj.com/articles/the-wealth-gap-shrinks-11601420393

According to an op-ed piece by the Wall Street Journal Editorial Board, the Federal Reserve has published a report (https://www.federalreserve.gov/econres/scfindex.htm, I believe, or https://www.federalreserve.gov/publications/files/scf20.pdf for a somewhat more readable version) indicating that the lowest-income households in the US increased in overall income and savings during the pre-pandemic Trump years while the wealthiest mostly stayed where they were or dipped a little.  Is this an accurate description of the overall findings of the report?  (For example, is this an accurate description overall, or are they carefully selecting the data points that support their argument while ignoring those that do not?)  If so, how credible is the report itself?

Specific claims (about the period from 2016-2019) include:

- "middle- and low-income earners [have] benefitted tremendously over the last three years"
- "Median real incomes grew 5% from 2016 to 2019, the Fed reports,"
- "families at the top of the income and wealth distributions experienced very little, if any, growth in net worth between 2016 and 2019 after experiencing large gains between 2013 and 2016 while families near the bottom of the income and wealth distributions generally continued to experience substantial gains."
- "more broadly, the income gaps between families with a college degree and those without one decreased.  Real median incomes grew 9% for Americans who haven’t completed high school and 6.3% for those with only a high-school diploma while declining 2.3% among those with a college degree."

Again, I am specifically interested in the following information.

- Does the Federal Reserve Survey of Consumer Finances 2019 essentially say these things?
- Is this an accurate description of the overall situation (that the wealth gap shrank during those years), or is the WSJ cherry-picking specific facts out of a larger survey to present a heavily biased picture?
- If that is generally what the survey says, is there any reason to doubt its accuracy?

Comment: You need to actually cite a "notable claim".  And, when you do this, ask whether the observed effects take into account the "momentum" from the Obama administration.

Comment: @DanielRHicks doesn't "The editors of the WSJ posted an Op-Ed stating that the Wealth Gam shrunk" count as a "notable claim"?  Specifically, they're making a (notable) claim that the Federal Reserve is making a (notable) claim, and I'm questioning both of them.  I'm also linking an article where they make a number of supporting claims (again, all notable) that I'm at least vaguely questioning by implication.

Comment: @DanielRHicks as far as "momentum", the same op-ed claims that under Obama, it actually got worse.  I didn't choose to include that claim in my question, but it would seem to cover the momentum question.  Further, while it might be interesting, it wasn't explicitly part of the claim made, and therefore isn't something I'm officially questioning.  If you wish to give an answer that includes that factor, that would be great.

Comment: It takes several years for the economy to respond.

Comment: How is "but it buries ..." a notable claim?

Comment: @DanielRHicks Whther or not the information was "buried" isn't particularly interesting to me, and wasn't the claim I was challenging... but even so, it is a claim (that the report de-emphasized certain points) and it is notable (the editors of the WSJ posting an op-ed in that publication).  Are you challenging the notability, or the idea that it's a claim at all?  It seemed to me that the claim I'm questioning (and I am questioning it) was pretty clearly laid out in the initial question.  If you feel it was not, could you clarify what would be necessary to properly lay it out for you?

Comment: My point is that you didn't quote the article, and what one can read online without an account ends with "but it buries ...".  So there's nothing notable.

Comment: @DanielRHicks ah.  So... as it turns out, where the paywall hits is heavily dependent on browser.  I've included some specific claims.  Is that better?

Comment: @DanielRHicks Funny how it only takes several years for the economy to respond if it's your opponent who's in charge and your guy who was previously in charge.

Comment: There are a variety of issues here:  (a) a more readable version of the Fed analysis is at https://www.federalreserve.gov/publications/files/scf20.pdf (b) there is a distinction between the distribution of income and of wealth (c) the income part of this report seems to look solely at pre-tax income (d) for some of the indicators the means and medians seem to show different patterns (e) there are also some differences in relative changes whether measure in percentages or in dollars (f) the report itself is based on a survey and so is sensitive at the top end to who is surveyed each time ...

Comment: That being said, the overall thrust of the report is that the headlines can broadly be said to reflect what this report and survey say for the changes from 2016 to 2019.  Tables 1 and 2 of the pdf give reasonable summaries of the results of the survey

Comment: @pipe: Who ever said "only"?

Comment: @DevSolar I believe you've misparsed that "only".  He's suggesting that if the roles were reversed, then Mr Hicks would not be so quick to suggest that wealth gap shrinkage during a Democratic presidency was the result of the policies of a preceding Republican presidency.

Comment: @BenBarden: ...by which he is turning Mr. Hicks' de-facto (and IMHO correct) statement into an accusation of political agenda, *plus* insinuating dishonesty on Mr. Hicks' part.

Comment: @DevSolar I agree that including the effects of momentum as context in the answer of a question like this (to the degree that you can find support for it) would be entirely appropriate, and add to the overall quality of the answer.  I'd welcome such a thing. 
 Applying an imperative that they be included up front in the *question*, however, does suggest something of an agenda (conscious or otherwise), especially given how ill-defined and subject to bias judgments of momentum often are in cases like this.

Comment: There is no "imperative" here. Daniel voiced his opinion on how, in *his* opinion, your question could be made better.

Comment: @DevSolar "And, when you do this, ask..." is an imperative.  That's what an imperative is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115172/discussion-between-devsolar-and-ben-barden).

Comment: @DanielRHicks Obama had the worst recovery in history, not hyperbole at all.  There was literally zero momentum.

Comment: @KDog regardless of the truth-value of that statement (which I do not know with certainty, and refuse to comment on) it's getting rather badly off the topic.  I recognize that I myself have strayed some distance from the topic at hand, but I'd like to pull back, and, preferably, to try to depoliticize this as much as can reasonably be done.

Comment: Your title talks about wealth, but most of the claims in your bulleted list are about income. Which are you asking about?

Comment: @shoover I'm asking about the claims in this particular Op-ed in the wall street journal, which had a title about the wealth gap shrinking, and the listed claims in the body.  If you can present evidence that the things they're discussing aren't actually part of what's colloquially thought of as "wealth gap" that would absolutely be a useful contribution to the discussion.  My understanding (limited as it sometimes is) was that when people talk about "wealth gap" these days, income is a big part of what they're discussing.

Comment: Income and wealth are not the same. After I retire, I will likely be wealthy, but I will have little or no income. Contrarily, there are people whose income is quite high who have little wealth to show for it because they spend it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding income, the board's pdf (which you've linked to) says on the first page e.g. that

> Between 2016 and 2019, median family income rose 5 percent, and mean family income
> decreased 3 percent (figure 1). These changes suggest that the income distribution
> narrowed slightly over the period, particularly as the decrease in mean income was
> mainly driven by families in the top 1 percent of the income distribution (see box 1, “The
> Data Used in This Article”)
>
> Between 2016 and 2019, families that were high wealth, had a college education, or identified as White non-Hispanic experienced proportionally smaller income growth than
> other groups of families but continued to have the highest income

As noted in the comments, income is not wealth, and you haven't quoted anything WSJ said on wealth, except in the headline "The Wealth Gap Shrinks". But even on that the board's pdf e.g. says (p.2):

> Families at the top of the income and wealth distributions experienced very little, if any, growth in median and mean net worth between 2016 and 2019 after experiencing large
> gains between 2013 and 2016
>
> Families near the bottom of the income and wealth distributions generally continued to
> experience substantial gains in median and mean net worth between 2016 and 2019.

The SCF survey itself is [not new](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survey_of_Consumer_Finances) having been conducted for almost 3 decades now. I rather doubt there is any devastating critique of its methodology somewhere (and hasn't made it to Wikipedia)...

I'm really not sure why this was even a question here. If you really want to ask "how is this possible", economics SE is a better place to ask that... If you want a hint for that, the recovery in wealth after the 2008 crash [appears](https://www.federalreserve.gov/econres/notes/feds-notes/wealth-and-income-concentration-in-the-scf-20200928.htm) to have had longer lags in the lower tiers.

[image]

They even dare say that (after some commentary that the absolute change is small--a fact evident from the graph too):

> The data collected in the 2010–2016 SCF surveys indicated that the sustained economic growth that followed the Great Recession had initially accrued primarily to the wealthiest families. These 2019 data were collected at the end of the longest economic expansion on record, when growth spread more equitably to the larger segments of the distribution.

Comment: I brought it to Skeptics under "this looked at least somewhat credible but clashed strongly with my preconceptions".  That seems to me to be an eminently reasonable reason to ask a question here.  As far as your answer, you've presented some reasonable quotes and evidence, but the answer would be improved by finishing with a straightforward statement as to conclusion and level of certainty